# Getting Entity in Doctrine Listener

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 4 entities in my application Agency, Facilitator, Entry and EntryImage in my application. An Agency has multiple Facilitators who in turn make Entries into the system posting multiple EntryImages for each Entry.

I have a postPersist listener which performs actions depending on the entities, which works well when I save an Agency or Facilitator but not Entry or EntryImage. Here is the code below

```
<?php
namespace ACME\MyBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Agency;
use ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Facilitator;
use ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Entry;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Twig_Environment as Environment;

class UserListener
{
protected $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    if ($entity instanceof Agency || $entity instanceof Facilitator) 
    {
        $templateFile = "ACMEMyBundle:Default:email.html.twig";
        $templateContent = $this->container->get('twig')->loadTemplate($templateFile);
        $password = $entity->randomPassword();
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($entity->getEmail());
        $user->setEmail($entity->getEmail());
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $userManager->updateUser($user, true);


        if ($entity instanceof Agency) 
        {
            $group = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Group')->findOneBy(array('id' => 2)); 
            $name = $entity->getName();
            $email = array($entity->getContactEmail(),$entity->getAlternativeContactEmail());
        }
        if ($entity instanceof Facilitator) 
        {
            $group = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Group')->findOneBy(array('id' => 3));
            $name = $entity->getFirstName().' '.$entity->getMiddleNames().' '.$entity->getSurname();
            $email = $entity->getEmail();
        }
        $body = $templateContent->render(array('name' => $name, 'password' => $password, 'username' => $entity->getEmail()));

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Registration to OLX Moving Cheese Portal')
                ->setFrom(array('movingcheese@localhost.com' => 'Moving Cheese'))
                ->setTo($entity->getEmail())
                ->setCC($email)
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setReplyTo(array('marvin@localhost.com', 'rita@localhost.com'))
                ->setBody($body)
            ;
            $this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);

        $current_user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $u = $userManager->findUserByUsername($entity->getEmail());
        $u->addGroup($group);
        $entity->setUser($u);
        if ($entity instanceof Facilitator) 
        {
            $agency = $em->getRepository('ACMEMyBundle:Agency')->findOneBy(array('user' => $current_user));
            $entity->setAgency($agency);
            $entity->setCreatedBy($current_user->getId());
        }
        $em->persist($u);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
    if ($entity instanceof Entry) 
    {
        $u = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $entity->setUser($u);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

}

The issue is the line below evaluates fine when I'm saving a Facilitator or Agency

```
if ($entity instanceof Agency || $entity instanceof Facilitator)
```

But this line below doesn't evaluate when I try to save and Entry object even when dumping the $entity shows clearly an object is passed.

```
if ($entity instanceof Entry)
```

I don't know whether this is of any significance but maybe i should mention that I have embedded an EntryImageAdmin into EntryAdmin form

Comment: Did you add proper `use` statement for `Entry` class at the top of your listener class? Ex: `use Acme/MyBundle/Entity/Entry`.

Comment: I'd first forgotten that but on adding it there has been no change, I am editing question to post whole class

Comment: Sorry about this, my query at the front-end was correct after after i added the above line. Thanks for taking your time